# Taking auth information from req.headers, instantiating an "API class" and attaching it to res.locals... how can I best structure the class methods?

Tags: node.js, express

## Introduction

I am creating an API wrapper for a ticketing system in Express. I suppose it could be defined as an API CORS proxy where I'm writing some custom API calls, along with using some basic ones that the ticketing system provides.

My Express app uses my custom middleware where I take certain variables from `req.headers` and use them to instantiate a class. I put the newly instantiated class in `res.locals` and extract that class in each route to make the API calls. If I didn't do this I would be duplicating a lot of code, extracting `req.headers` in every route and passing values to every custom API function I create.

I'm just unsure if I'm making any awkward, round-about choices here and if there is a best practice to be followed that I haven't thought of. It doesn't seem like my use case is all that unique.

## The Underlying Code

I have `ticketingsystem.js` where I  create the "base API" to interact with, so I do not have to repeat it every time:

```
const axios = require("axios");

const API_URL = `/v4_6_release/apis/3.0/`;

const Tickets = require("./service/Tickets");

class TicketingSystem {
  constructor(props) {
    this.authKey = props.authKey;
    this.URL = props.URL;
    this.api_URL = props.API_URL || API_URL;
    this.rootAPI = axios.create({
      baseURL: `https://${this.URL}/v4_6_release/apis/3.0/`,
      headers: {
        Authorization: `${this.authKey}`,
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      timeout: 5000
    });
    this.tickets = new Tickets({ self: this });
  }
  api(REQUEST_CONFIG) {
    return this.rootAPI(REQUEST_CONFIG)
      .then(response => {
        this.logSuccess(response.status, REQUEST_CONFIG);
        return response;
      })
      .catch(e => {
        this.handleError(e, REQUEST_CONFIG);
      });
  }
// ... methods logSuccess and handleError... //
}
```

The `Tickets` class in the last line of the constructor is from `Tickets.js`:

```
class Tickets {
  constructor(props) {
    this.get = () => {
      const REQUEST_CONFIG = { method: "GET", url: `/service/tickets/` };
      return props.self.api(REQUEST_CONFIG);
    };
    this.getByID = id => {
      const REQUEST_CONFIG = {
        method: "GET",
        url: `/service/tickets/${id}/`
      };
      return props.self.api(REQUEST_CONFIG);
    };
  }
}

module.exports = Tickets;
```

## The Result

What this all allows me to do is a create a route looking something like this (just as an example):

```
// ...Middleware to create new obj from class TicketingSystem() and storing in res.locals.api... //

app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  const API = res.locals.api;
  try {
    const result = await API.tickets.getByID("340294");
    res.send(JSON.stringify(result.data));
  } catch (e) {
    res.sendStatus(e);
  }
});
```

`const API = res.locals.api` is me taking the class created in the middleware out and using the method attached to it: `API.tickets.getByID()`

## My Question

Is it normal to write this how I am writing it? That is:

- The overall structure of using classes to create an API object on every Express request
- Using classes within classes for the API's methods.

If so, it also seems "hacky" to use `this.tickets = new Tickets({self: this});` in the "base API" and the `props.self.api` in the "Tickets" code.

Should I instead just have a gigantic chunk of methods on the "base API"? That is what I'm trying to avoid but don't want to end up doing something strange. Is there a better way to be doing this altogether?